# Is there any logic to which potions you get from rituals?

Tags: king-of-thieves

In King of Thieves, when you perform a ritual with gems of the same color, you are awarded a potion. But is there any logic to which potion you get, or is it completely random?

Answer (score 2):

The potions which you receive are *not* random.

- All red gems - Disable trap
- All yellow gems - 2x Gold
- All green gems - Slow motion
- All blue gems - Gang of thieves
- All purple gems - Ghost

Edit: unique gems can no longer be run in rituals